# Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/styles/colors'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code, that does not compiled:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppBar, Toolbar } from 'material-ui';
import { Typography } from 'material-ui';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import {cyan, red} from 'material-ui/colors';
import { red400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';


const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: red400,
    secondary: cyan, 
  },
});

const View = (props) => (
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
      <Typography variant="title">
        {props.title}
      </Typography>          
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
export default View;
```

It says:

```
Failed to compile
./src/Dashboard/AppBar/Views/View.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/styles/colors' in '/home/developer/Desktop/react-reason/example/src/Dashboard/AppBar/Views'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run `npm install material-ui@next` ? I had a similar problem because I ran `npm install material-ui` which installs the older version

Comment: I also thing using `red400` is not correct.. Perhaps try `primary: red[400]` instead and remove the extra `import { red400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'`?

Comment: I installed only `npm install material-ui@next`. Is it not enough?

Comment: Yes, using only `npm install material-ui@next` should be sufficient. My best guess is the problem is in the import statement `import { red400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'`. I would suggest removing that and using ONLY `import {cyan, red} from 'material-ui/colors';` In my projects I use it like this : `import green from 'material-ui/colors/green';` And then `primary: green`.

Comment: I removed `import { red400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'`, changed `primary: red[400]` and I've got `TypeError: Cannot create property 'light' on string '#ef5350'`

Comment: In that case, try: `primary:{main:red[400]}`

Comment: And how to for example `A400`.

Comment: `primary:{main:red['A400']}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168647/discussion-between-zero-coding-and-chirag-ravindra).

Comment: how to change the font color to white. On `A400` has white font color as you can see on https://material-ui-next.com/style/color/. But I've got black font color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moving the discussion in the comments here:

Make sure you install the `next` version of material-ui:

`npm install material-ui@next`

This import statement is incorrect:

`import { red400 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'`

It needs to be like:

`import red from 'material-ui/colors/red';`

Here, `red` is what the docs call a 'color object'.
You can then use it in to create your theme object like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: red[500], //OR red['A400'] for the accent range
      contrastText: '#fff', // The text color to use
      // You can also specify light, dark variants to use (it's autocomputed otherwise)
    }
    //You can also just assign the color object if the defaults work for you
    secondary: red,
    error: red
    //tonalOffset
    //contrastThreshold

  },
});
```

In the above code, the keys `primary` `secondary` and `error` accept either a color object OR a 'palette intention' which is an object which looks like this:

```
interface PaletteIntention {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
};
```

The only required key there is `main`. The rest are auto computed from the value of `main` if it's not provided.

Reference:

[The docs have a detail section on themes which explains all of this in detail](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#palette).

Comment: I nominate you to rewrite their official documentation.

Comment: The package material-ui@next has beeb deprecated  to @material-ui/core

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i downloaded a template Material Dashboard Pro and was running
`npm install`
to install the dependencies but it was showing the same error so i fixed it with

```
npm install material-ui@next --force
```

by adding `--force` flag solved my issue. posting this because it may be helpful for someone.

Comment: I also use `--force` flag too Man!